# How do I programmatically find the user's logging directory?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Given an app called ExampleApp, I want to find "~/Library/Logs/ExampleApp" basically without using hard coded paths. There exists NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains, which you can use to find things like "~/Library/Application Support/ExampleApp" using the NSApplicationSupportDirectory search term, but there doesn't seem to be a search term for logging.

I don't think ~/Library/Logs is non-standard, since CrashReporter puts its logs there.

Comment: FYI: If you are planning on using the Mac App Store then you can't use the Library/Logs directory, it is not an approved directory. You need to put an application's log in its folder inside Application Support.

Comment: CRD: I thought a sandboxed app had unrestricted access to its container and subdirectories?  For example, on my system, there exists a directory ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Logs (there's nothing in it though)

Comment: That might be a gray area, but I think a *Mac App Store* sandboxed app gets access to the intersection of those folders allowed by the MAS and the sandbox container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
NSString* libraryPath = [NSHomeDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Logs"];
```

**Update *(~/Library/Logs/AppName)* :**

```
NSString* bundleName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"];
NSString* logsPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Library/Logs/%@",bundleName];

NSString* libraryPath = [NSHomeDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:logsPath];
```

Comment: I modified my question slightly to include the app's name.

Comment: nice! I ended up using NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,...) to get the user's Library directory but it's all good!

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa doesn't provide a means for finding all of the standard directories.  The old `FSFindFolder()` function can provide many more, but does involve converting from an FSRef back to a path or URL. Apple discourages its use, but it's still the only way to get certain standard directories without hard-coding.  That said, it won't ever incorporate your app name.  You have to append that.

Edited to add: the [link to the legacy docs](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Folder_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000238-CH1g-F16387).

Comment: In what way does Apple discourage its use?  As of the 10.7 SDK, it's not deprecated.

Comment: @JWWalker, find it in the non-legacy docs and I'll withdraw that claim. ;)

Comment: Well, things get moved to legacy wholesale but deprecated piecemeal, and I think deprecation is a more official way of discouraging a particular function.